# When is a PCIE endpoint/card powered?

Tags: pcie

At what point in host boot process, does a PCIE endpoint get powered ? 
Is it powered as soon as the host/PC starts booting or when it starts the enumeration process ?

References would be appreciated.

Comment: You are asking us to do research for you that you can do yourself by just Googling "PCIe". You will find hundreds of pages of data, including latest standards.